# KNIME: Looping per row with different from –> to values

Tags: loops, knime

i am trying to create a loop that takes in the from and to values from each row of a table to loop this amount of times. The current loop value should be multiplied by the revenue value.

Example: For ID WW380 the Loop should go from 1 to 5, for WW326 from 3 to 10 etc.

| ID | from | to | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WW380 | 1 | 5 | 8518 |
| WW326 | 3 | 10 | 10518 |
| WW270 | 6 | 15 | 3518 |
| WW48X | 8 | 20 | 6518 |
| WW384 | 3 | 30 | 3518 |

Is something like this possible with the Loops in KNIME?

Best regards
Timo

Answer (score 0):

someone from the knime forum helped out here and provided the answer
[here](https://forum.knime.com/t/looping-per-row-with-different-from-to-values/31777)

Best regards
Timo